# Function defined without a prototype sometimes results in conflicting types error

Tags: c, clang

I have encountered a strange behaviour in clang (both AppleClang 1400.0.29.202 and clang 15.0.7 from Homebrew). Assume I have the following code:

```
int bar();

int bar(int a, TEST b) {
    return 43;
}
```

It compiles with `-DTEST=int` but fails to compile with `-DTEST=char`resulting in `conflicting types for 'bar'`. This happens regardless of the specified standard (I have tried `c89` and `c99`).

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I realise that omitting prototypes is highly discouraged and I don't write code like this, but there's still a lot of code written like this in the wild. I was trying to compile `enscript` this morning and encountered this issue.

Also, the following works with `-DTEST=char`.

```
int bar();

int bar(a, b)
    int a;
    TEST b;
{
    return 43;
}
```

**EDIT2:** I should have tried it with other compilers before asking. GCC output contains a note about argument promotion:

```
note: an argument type that has a default promotion cannot match an empty parameter name list declaration
```

Comment: I guess it is because it conflicts with the default argument promotions.

Comment: *Am I missing something?*  Yes - a proper function prototype.  Don't write code like that.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: (Btw this old, long since obsolescent crap is finally getting removed from the C language in C23.)

Comment: `-DTEST=int` is giving  two warnings that tell pretty much about it: https://godbolt.org/z/rvGqGaj68

Comment: I don't write such code and am really glad that C2x gets rid of it, but unfortunately there's still a lot of existing code using it.

Comment: @nightuser That code is fundamentally broken, and it has always been broken.  It's not valid K&R C, nor is it valid under any ANSI or ISO standard.  If you're tasked with making it work, the only possible reply is, "It needs to be rewritten."

Comment: "*If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions.*" (Note: "parameter type list" means the function declaration is in function prototype form.) `char` is promoted to a type that is not compatible with `char` by the default argument promotions of most implementations.

Comment: You could make it work by using a K&R1 style function definition (at least until C23). `int bar(a, b) int a; TEST b; { return 43; }`. BTW, there is an off-by-one error in the return value. :)

Comment: @IanAbbott  Then someone would come along and "fix" things by adding actual function prototypes while leaving the K&R definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, a proper function declaration. The code should have been:

```
int bar(int a, TEST b);

int bar(int a, TEST b) {
    return 43;
}
```

> [Why I am getting this error?]

`int  bar()` is a function with *unspecified* count and type of arguments and all arguments undergo [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), where a `char` is promoted to an `int`. Because it's impossible for `int bar()` to take a `char` argument, because it would be promoted to an `int`, that is a conflicting type.